# How to solve a cubic function in R

Tags: r, equation, solver

Good day to all!

I have a following cubic equation.

```
Left <- P^3+4*P^2+6*P
Right <- 2
```

How do I get R to solve for `P` to get `Left = Right`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to find the roots of `P^3+4P^2+6P = 2`?

Comment: Yes, what is P for the equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1. `uniroot()`

You could use `uniroot()` to search for a root of a function with respect to its first argument.

```r
uniroot(\(x, y) x^3 + 4*x^2 + 6*x - y, c(0, 1), y = 2, extendInt = "yes")

$root
[1] 0.278161

$f.root
[1] -1.779565e-05

$iter
[1] 6

$init.it
[1] NA

$estim.prec
[1] 6.103516e-05
```

#### 2. `polyroot()`

If the function is a real or complex polynomial, you could specifically use `polyroot(z)`, where `z` is the vector of polynomial coefficients in ***increasing*** order.

```r
y <- 2
polyroot(c(-y, 6, 4, 1))

# [1]  0.2781631-0.000000i -2.1390815+1.616897i -2.1390815-1.616897i
```

Both approaches solve the equation with the root `0.278161`. (Besides a real root, `polyroot` also gives two ***imaginary roots***)

Answer (score 1):

If you want symbolic solutions, I guess you can try `Ryacas` like below

```
> library(Ryacas)

> yac_str("Solve(P^3+4*P^2+6*P==2,P)")
[1] "{P==(71/27+Sqrt(187/27))^(1/3)-(Sqrt(187/27)-71/27)^(1/3)-4/3,P==Complex(-(4/3+((71/27+Sqrt(187/27))^(1/3)-(Sqrt(187/27)-71/27)^(1/3))/2),Sqrt(3/4)*((71/27+Sqrt(187/27))^(1/3)+(Sqrt(187/27)-71/27)^(1/3))),P==Complex(-(4/3+((71/27+Sqrt(187/27))^(1/3)-(Sqrt(187/27)-71/27)^(1/3))/2),-Sqrt(3/4)*((71/27+Sqrt(187/27))^(1/3)+(Sqrt(187/27)-71/27)^(1/3)))}"
```